# Linux Mint KDE won't shut down properly

Tags: linux-mint, kde, shutdown

I have bought a HP Pavilion Power 15-cb006ng and installed Linux Mint KDE on it. However, shortly after I started using it, it wouldn't shut down properly anymore. The first time it happened, I could get it down using "Alt+F7", but at some point that stopped working. The only solution left to me right now is the hard shut down, which is of course not a good way. This is what I see upon every shutdown:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend to you boot other kernel. You must have boot menu (`GRUB`) which allow you to select kernel version. Something wrong with `nouveau` module or it's boot parameters. You can review your boot parameters for current and old kernel (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) in line that begins with `kernel` word too. There are many other problems exists in same situations. But it's a start point for examine. So, at first, please try to load with old kernel and write about it.

Comment: Hah! I reverted to kernel 4.10 and it worked again. However, this is a bug that needs treatment right? Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know about downvote. I haven't voted. So, problem with module. Sometimes situation like this are happen. From start of this week many questions about bugs with virtualbox modules in Mint registered. So I think new updates will be soon. Also, you can take strong system knowns and rebuild kernel and modules by own. But I think it's better wait and give new updates from distro vendor. You can write about this bug to Mint bug-tracker and maybe updates will be sooner.

Comment: I've just voted to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original cause of this issue remains unknown, however there is a fix:

Try out older versions of kernels until one works. The easiest way is to use the [Ubuntu Kernel Upgrade Utility](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html) and then select to boot with the older kernel in GRUB. Once the desired kernel is found, uninstall all newer ones so that the working one becomes the default.

In the meantime, while the PC is not able to shutdown properly, use [REISUB](http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/) to at least achieve a somewhat gentle shutdown/restart.